# How can i know that my Youtube API Data is correct?

Tags: api, python-requests, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-python-api

I having some trouble to understand something related to the API of youtube 
**So my code is basically very simple:**

```
name  = input("enter the username: ")
key = "MY API KEY"


data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
part=statistics&forUsername="+name+"&key="+key).read()
subs = json.loads(data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]

print(name + " has " + "{:,d}".format(int(subs)) + " subscribers!")
```

just yelling the number of subscribers after giving specific YouTube Username: 
The thing is that some Usernames(for example: Vsuase/Veritasium/Unbox Therapy ) which have many subs and the API-URL giving me wrong Data

Vsause - in return giving me back 72 subs

Veritasium/Unbox Therapy - not giving my any number at all

**BUT**, a channel "Computerphile" giving me that exact same subs they have.

**How come that few Usernames work and few do not??**

Answer (score 0):

I tested in both, using the *try-it* functionality available in the [YouTube Data API - Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) and in the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/) and in both sites the results are *closely*<sup>1</sup> similar.

For example, when the statistics of the YouTube user `vsauce` is requested vía YouTube API, the value in `subscriberCount` is `14220819` and checking his YouTube channel it says: `14,220,825`.

Here is the [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22statistics%22%2C%22forUsername%22%3A%22vsauce%22%7D) for request the statistics of the YouTube user `vsauce` *(using the try-it)*

And here is the [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=statistics&forUsername=vsauce&fields=items%252Fstatistics&_h=3&) for request the statistics of the YouTube user `vsauce` *(using the Google API Explorer)*.

I didn't see any differences in the values in `subscriberCount` by requesting the other channels you mentioned in your question.

---

<sup>1</sup> You need consider that some channels has more changes in the quantity of subscribers than others and such results vary too in the responses of the API.

Comment: i get why when i try to load "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=vsause&key=AIzaSyDjnINqqxQlIg4kbXoPDVYOhHNfdmDbb9I" i only get ---- "subscriberCount": "72",----

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you change in the URL from forUsernae= --> id=
it gives you the correct numbers.

TED channel:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&**id=UCAuUUnT6oDeKwE6v1NGQxug**&key=AIzaSyDjnINqqxQlIg4kbXoPDVYOhHNfdmDbb9I